# Is Capacitive/Clock Feedthrough signal-dependant?

Tags: switches

I am wondering about the phenomenon of capacitive/clock feedthrough in a simple MOS device with a hold capacitor.

For example consider the following
[image]

If a parasitic Cgs appears, then surely Q = CV and the voltage V is the difference between the gate voltage and the output voltage which is signal dependant as the hold capacitor will store a value close to the input voltage.

So my conclusion is that clock/capacitive feedthrough will cause a signal dependant drop on the hold capacitor. Is that correct?

Comment: The V in the Q=CV should surely be the deltaV of the CK signal, not the difference between the clock and Vout. It is independent of the signal voltage. However, Cgs may be dependent on Vout.

Comment: @KevinWhite Why is it the deltaV of the CK signal? The voltage across Cgs is the CK voltage - the output voltage?

Comment: The charge injection is proportional to the the voltage across the capacitor after the clock edge minus the voltage across the capacitor before the clock edge. That is the change in the voltage of the clock. This is independent of the signal voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is always feedthru noise from charge injection **amplified by input voltage.**

[image]

• **Transmission gate reduces charge injection since the charge carriers since some of the  CMOS transmission gate injected charges cancel out**
• PMOS and NMOS are hard to match in size, capacitances, reducing this benefit.

[image]
[image]

Others

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from what I remember, the charge will be unevenly split between Source and Drain, because those usually will have different impedances (capacitances mostly, when gate is switched in a few nanoseconds).